# Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "" to Array

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, flash

Having difficulty grabbing data from an XML and putting it into an Array.

At the start of my document my array looks like this:

```
// MC's in library with exported for AS with class names "page1", "page2", etc.
var pageArray:Array = [new page1(), new page2(), new page3(), new page4(), new page5()];
```

Which all works well and fine when I navigate through the array.

Then my problem comes when I try to replace that array with a new array from an XML file, from within a MovieClip.

```
/..xml details etc../
var pages_xml:String = xmlData.account.(@code == String(codeField.text)).pages;
MovieClip(root).pageArray = pages_xml;
```

An example of a line from my XML would look like this.

```
<account code="1"><accountName>Account1</accountName><pages>new page1(), new page2()</pages></account>
```

So from my example above you can see that I'm just trying to replace **new page1(), new page2(), new page3()** with **new page1(), new page2()**
But doing so results in this error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "new page1(), new page2()" to Array.

I know the best way would probably be to splice or something but the arrays will be getting messy later on and I will probably over up to 50 pages (a different selection of pages for each account code).

Would appreciate any ideas on what I can do or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is taking a string and assigning it to be an Array... instead it seems you want to create instances of a class based on a string as you say you'll have to parse the string then create new instances using something like

```
var parsedString:Array = pages_xml.split(",");
MovieClip(root).pageArray=[];
for(var i:int=0;i<parsedString.length;i++)
{
    var clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName(parsedString[i]) as Class;
    MovieClip(root).pageArray.push(new clazz());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried your code and understand what I seem to be doing wrong. I am having an issue still though, the arrays don't seem to be loading properly?

I ran trace( MovieClip(root).pageArray); and it output returns
`,,`

Comment: Actually I didn't see your edit, I've updated it with the new script and it works great!
I had to amend the XML to read **page1,page2,page3** instead of **new page1(),new page2(),new page3()** which is much more convenient for me anyway.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Cool no problem, yeah I had to edit quite a few times, kept second guessing parts and modifying for a few minutes there, anyhow glad it worked out for ya.